# How to Hide/Show keypad of android upon some conditon

Tags: android, android-keypad

I need to Hide keypad when press Button-1 and so the Mobile will Hide the keypad for all purpose in all application.
After that i want to SHOW it when i press Button-2.
Actually i am developing an application where when speed of Vehicle increase then it shod hide it and when decrease then show again.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

To hide your keyboard you can do

```
View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
                if (view != null && mCustomEndpoint.hasFocus()) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
```

To show the keyboard, you just have to call `editText.requestFocus()` on the edittext for which you want to show keyboard

Comment: No i want to hide keypad not just for my app but for the whole application installed on the device.Once i press Button-1 Mobile will not be able to open keypad for any app

Comment: sir, can you please help me in this

Comment: Thank you i will waiting for you,